# File that was read into R: is it still being 'accessed' or ping? Same question for Shiny

Tags: r

Let's say my R code reads in a csv file as a data frame and then does calculations on it.
Is that csv file still being "used" or "accessed" after it was read in - from the point of view of the computer?

Same question for R shiny...

Thank you very much!

Comment: No, once you read it in, there is nothing "holding on" to the file. If the file changes, shiny is not aware unless you use [`reactiveFileReader`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.4.0/reactiveFileReader.html) or some form of [reactive poll](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/reactive-poll-and-file-reader.html).

Comment: Thank you! That's what I thought but wanted to make sure.